# programmatically scrolling a TreeViewer in SWT

Tags: tree, treeview, swt, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have two TreeViewer components. The horizontal scroll bars have to be synchronized. I have tried with setSelection and setTopItem methods but both have no effect to other tree. only the ScrollBar is moved but not the tree .

```
final ScrollBar rightScrollBar = tree_1.getHorizontalBar();
rightScrollBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
             //       tree.setSelection(tree_1.getSelection());
        }
    });
```

Any idea Please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately programmatic horizontal scrolling is not possible. In fact, scrolling in general by using the `ScrollBar` objects isn't possible at all. The method `setTopItem(TreeItem item)` that you mentioned is only for **vertical** scrolling which isn't what you're looking, right? But for vertical scrolling that method should work.